# switching between certain component on a page using nested route in react router

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, react-router

I am trying to create a job site. Following pages shows list of all the jobs which is shown once user hits search button from home page. So basically this is the second page.

In this page i am catching all the search parameter from url and fetching data from api and result is shown as below:

[image]

Once the user clicks individual joblist, detail page should load on the same page without changing header and fixed component with unique URL for the detail page. Expected result shown below:

[image]

**My Problem:** 
***I manage to create a nested Route, which renders detail page on the same page and also has a unique url. But it renders on top of existing job list. I mean if user clicks on joblist1, detail page renders on top of subsiquent list(above list: 2, 3, 4). But expected result is to only render detail page but not list of jobs when individual job list is clicked.***

My code: I have only shown part of the code for brevity and simplicity.

1) jobs.js: Passes state data to child component to show list.

```
return(
 <div>
   <div>
       fixed component
   </div>
   <div>
       <RouteHandler />
       <JobLists joblists={this.state.joblists} />
   </div>
 </div>
)
```

2) jobList.js: uses .map function to go through all data and handleclick function generate url and opens that url once user clicks individual link. Router catches nested route and loads value inside jobs.js in " ".

```
handleClick: function(i){
   var base_path = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host;
   base_path += '/#/jobs-detail';
   window.location= base_path;
},

render: function(){
    var jobListRow = this.props.joblists.map(function(jobrowobj, i){
        return(
        <div key={jobrowobj.id} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, i)}>
          <img src={jobrowobj.logo} alt="" />
          <h3>{jobrowobj.title}</h3>
        </div>
       )  
    }.bind(this));

    return(
        <ul id="joblists">
            {jobListRow}
        </ul>
    )
}
```

3)  Route file:

```
var routes = (
  <Route handler={App}>
    <DefaultRoute handler={Home} />
    <Route name="jobs" path="jobs" handler={Jobs}>
        <Route name="jobs-detail" handler={JobDetail} />
    </Route>
    <NotFoundRoute handler={NotFoundPage} />
  </Route>
);
```

I am not sure what is the best way to switch certain section (component) on a page as in my case switching between joblist component and jobdetail component. As you can see i am only able to load other component on top of existing component which is not the expected result.

***Also would appreciate if any hint is given to maintain scroll position on the job list on user hitting back button.***

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to upgrade your react-router to 1.0.0-rc1, and the API is more clear. Your problem is similar to the [official introduction](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/Introduction.md). The nested component will be passed as `this.props.children`, and you can insert it into the `jobListRow`.

About the scroll position, there's a [github issue](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/1686) discussing how to restore it :)